# Coloring of Select html element by jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I need some help with jQuery script again :-)  Just trying to play with jQuery..I use script below for coloring options of select element. It works in pure html, but in my asp.net 2.0 (Master + Content pages) does not. Script is placed in Head section.

```
function pageLoad(){
   var allOddSelectOption  = "select option:odd";
   var evenStyle = "background-color:'#f4f4f4';color:'#555'";

   $(allOddSelectOption).attr('style',evenStyle);
}
```

I tried also use `$(document).ready(function(){` but it didn't work too.

Any ideas, tips most welcome?

Comment: I would need to see more code than this.  can you post more.  It may be something with the DOCTYPE.  Did you put an alert in the code to make sure the code is getting executed?

Comment: yes it gets inside, but no coloring is implemented... I may try tip in first answer, just use css instead of style. But still its' wierd that it works in pure html and it doen't in asp.net...will see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [css(properties)](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#properties), you can apply styles very easy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select option:odd").css({'background-color' : 'yellow', 'font-weight' : 'bolder'});
});
```

EDIT: For ASP .NET 2.0 `$(document).ready()` will work, since you can call it [multiple times](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready) you will have no problem even if it's not in the head section.

---

For ASP .NET 3.5

You can add in your MasterPage a head placeholder like this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

and then in your child pages you can put html into it by a Content tag:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
  <script language="JavaScript>
    //Scripts here!
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say in every case to use .addClass rather than add inline css attributes. These are hard to maintain in javascript.

```
e.g $('#someDiv').addClass('odd');
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net decorates your element IDs when you are using master pages. It will put a lot of stuff up front, but leave your original ID at the end. Because of that, you can use a selector like this on ASP.Net server control renderings.

```
$("[id$=originalIdFromAspxPage]").attr...
```

The `$=` part means this will match any elements with an ID that ends with the ID you give it.

It's not quite as efficient as a direct ID selector, but it works like a charm on ASP.Net pages.

Comment: well I know about this ....so that is the reason I try to use only select element and not id ;-)

Comment: Yeah, all of ASP.NET's automagic seems nice until you try to make it play nice with the rest of the web development world.  It's easy to run into magic problems.